# 2003 Tibaron ECU fuse blows while driving, not when idling

Tags: electrical, hyundai

This is a 2003 Tibaron.

The ECU fuse blows only when driving. It can idle for hours. What runs off the ecu fuse?

I replaced the ECU, didn't help. Checked power and grounds, no problem found.

I'm trying to find out what the ECU fuse powers so I can isolate the circuit. Also, this problem started about 1 month after they replaced the clutch cable.

There are no codes !!!

Comment: It looks like the ECU fuse only powers the ECM memory circuit on a manual transmission car.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a short which occurs only under certain circumstances, like when the vehicle is going down the road.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a wiggle test. The clutch cables on that particular car is a real pain, and for someone who hasn't done it before, it's really easy to screw up wiring. My friend is a Hyundai Master Tech and hates working on them because of routing and space. It's sounding like a short somewhere, but you need to determine where.

Get yourself a new fuse, put it in. Start the car and find any and all harnesses you can near the vicinity of the fusebox and under the dash. It comes in under the brake master cylinder, and travels all the way to the ECU on the right passenger side. Gently wiggle on the harness until you can blow the fuse or get the ECU to stop working. There are much more expensive ways to do this professionally, but the tools are pretty expensive.

Here's the link if you're interested.

[http://www.amazon.com/Power-Probe-ECT2000-Circuit-Detector/dp/B000P6UO2I](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000P6UO2I)

It's never failed me and cheaper now. I paid $500 for mine. That's a steal for something like that.